# How to change the text-color of <summary> element after clicking it?

Tags: html, css

How to change the text-color of  element after clicking it? please suggest **CSS for summary on hover, and summary on visited**. I want to change the text-color in summary element.

Comment: No JavaScript allowed?

Comment: JavaScript also allowed. it will become another way for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<summary>Sample text</summary>
```

CSS:

This will change color on hover

```
summary:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

This will change color on click

```
summary:active{
    color:red;
}
```

Basically ,when the summary is clicked use `:active` , when it is hovered use `:hover`

So the :active and :hover are pseudo classes.

You can check out their documentation here:

***1.*** :active https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

***2.*** :hover https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover